# Lifetime of service instance in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I created service derived from

```
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service
```

implementing some requests. What is the lifetime of this service instance - e.g. is there created a new instance per call or is the instance cached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Services are not singletons. An instance is created with every request.

Take a look at the following test that ensures this [ServiceStack / tests / ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Tests / ServiceCreationTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Tests/ServiceCreationTests.cs?source=cc#L82)